# Capitalization of references

Tags: capitalization

This question is probably beyond the scope of just TeX, but certainly interesting to many.

When referencing a figure, a lemma, or an equation in a paper, is there a general rule of whether or not to capitalize the respective identifier, i.e.,
whether to write

> [...] as in equation (3) [...]

or

> [...] as in Equation (3) [...]

This is essentially the question if "Equation (3)" is a proper noun, or rather merely a description (much like "page 3" which I suppose everyone would agree on not to capitalize).

Comment: either way, the `cleverref` package allows you to make the changes globally using `\cref` and friends

Comment: This sounds like a question any reputable style guide (for the given language and discipline) would be able to answer.  It is unlikely that a general answer could be given that would satisfy anyone.  (E.g., the second option looks odd to me as an English speaker, but in German the first option would be unacceptable.)

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic. This could either go to [english.se] or perhaps to [academia.se], but more likely the former.

Comment: You're welcome. We can migrate this question to one of these pages once it's closed here. To do so, flag it for mod attention and specify your case as "other". I.e. you don't have to ask the question again on another site.